# Different location rules for /member/ and /member/ANYTHING in nginx conf

Tags: php, nginx

I need to write two different rewrite rules for nginx location. The rules logic are given below

1. URL/member/ => URL/member/ or URL/member/index.php
2. URL/member/AnyOtherString => URL/member/AnyOtherString.php

I have tried the following

```
location ~ /member {
        location = /member {
            return 301 /member/;
        }
        return 301 $uri.php;
    }
```

But it does not work.

Comment: What do you want if `AnyOtherString.php` does not exists? Should it return 404, or fall back to `index.php`?

Comment: It should return 404

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a test server at hand, but I think you can try something like this:

```
location = /member {# use exact match to terminate further lookup
    return 301 /member/;
}
location = /member/ {
    try_files "${uri}index.php" =404;
}
location /member/ {
    try_files $uri $uri.php =404;
}
```